# Actualizar string sacada por consola en Python

Tags: python, string, consola, print

Estoy tratando de actualizar un string impreso por pantalla que indica la evolución del proceso (porcentaje) pero no entiendo por que, no lo hace correctamente. Si que se actualiza el string pero también imprime un nuevo string cada vez que pasa por el `print` La instrucción que utilizo es:

```
percentage = 100*(i/size)
print("Completado: %.2d" % (percentage), end='\r')
```

La salida que obtengo por pantalla es:

```
Completado: 100ompletado: 34Completado: 46Completado: 53Completado: 
59Completado: 65Completado: 71Completado: 78Completado: 84Completado: 90Completado: 96
```

Entiendo que el flag `end='\r'` es el que hace que se actualice el string. Otras veces esto me ha funcionado sin problema, pero ahora no entiendo por que no. También he probado con la instrucción `sys.stdout.flush()` y tampoco funciona. Estoy en Spyder 4.1.5 y Conda sobre Windows.

Comment: El que `\r` te retroceda al inicio de la línea para sobreescribirla puede depender de qué consola uses para ejecutar. En una consola linux funcionará sin problemas. Creo que en una windows también funcionaría. Posiblemente lo que ocurre es que lo estás ejecutando directamente en Spyder y viendo la salida en una ventana del mismo

Comment: Ok. Voy a probar con una terminal dedicada a ver. Gracias!!

Comment: Tal cual @abulafia Ha sido cambiar eso y funciona perfectamente ;)